# JButton will not change colour when I change it's colour

Tags: java, swing, button, paint

I have a row of buttons which all have the same colour, green, except for the "selectedButton", which is orange. When I click on a button, it becomes the new selectedButton, and so it changes to orange, all others change to green. My code correctly changes the new JButton to orange, however doesn't change the previous one from orange to green.

If I call revalidate() and repaint() in the paintComponent() method it works perfectly, but something tells me that's a terrible idea, since the repaint() method just calls the paintComponent() method again, so I might end up in some kind of infinite recursion, but I haven't so far and I'm not sure why. I'm confident revalidate() and repaint() will solve the problem if placed in the best spot in my code, but where should I add them. I tired adding both after I change the colours for the buttons on a mouseReleased() event, but it didn't work.

```
class StudentButton extends JButton{
    private int index;
    private Color startGradient, endGradient;   //Used for colouring JButton
    private static StudentButton selectedButton;

    public StudentButton(int i, boolean isSelected) { this("", i, isSelected); }
    public StudentButton(String text, int i, boolean isSelected){
        super(text); index = i;
        if(isSelected)
            StudentButton.setSelectedButton(this);
            //Colour set to orange
            startGradient = new Color(234, 249, 99);
            endGradient = new Color(230, 252, 35);
        }
        else {
            //Colour set to green
            startGradient = new Color(159, 255, 76);
            endGradient = new Color(101, 183, 29);
        }

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

            //mouseReleased better than mouseClicked, since it always triggers for an attempted click
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                StudentButton selButton = StudentButton.getSelectedButton();
                selButton.setColourGradients(new Color(159, 255, 76), new Color(101, 183, 29));

                StudentButton newSelButton = (StudentButton)(e.getSource());
                newSelButton.setColourGradients(new Color(234, 249, 99), new Color(230, 252, 35));
                StudentButton.setSelectedButton(newSelButton);
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //tried adding revalidate() and repaint() here, wouldn't work
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        });

        setContentAreaFilled(false);   ///removes ugly button border
    }

    public static StudentButton getSelectedButton() { return selectedButton; }
    public static void setSelectedButton(StudentButton sb) { selectedButton = sb; }

    public void setColourGradients(Color start, Color end) {
        startGradient = start; endGradient = end;
        System.out.println("Button "+index+", set to colour"+start);
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        GradientPaint p;
        p = new GradientPaint(0, 0, startGradient,
                0, getHeight(), endGradient);

        g2.setPaint(p);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2.setPaint(g2.getPaint());
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //This makes the buttons change correctly, but seems like a very bad idea                
        revalidate(); repaint();
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public int getIndex() {return index;}
}
```

Comment: Try to call repaint method from the extended Class not the paint method (out of this method) `this.repaint()` , the JButton is the container in this case !

Comment: I tried that just now, had to add in the line StudentButton parent = this, and then inside the mouseReleased method I called parent.revalidate() and parent.repaint(), but it still deosn't work

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bo_Halim I've realised that I was calling repaint() and revalidate() on a single StudentButton object and not both that were changing in the mouseReleased() method. I've changed the mousePressed method so that it repaints bot the old selected button and the new selected button.

```
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                StudentButton selButton = StudentButton.getSelectedButton();
                selButton.setColourGradients(new Color(159, 255, 76), new Color(101, 183, 29));
                selButton.revalidate(); selButton.repaint();

                StudentButton newSelButton = (StudentButton)(e.getSource());
                newSelButton.setColourGradients(new Color(234, 249, 99), new Color(230, 252, 35));
                StudentButton.setSelectedButton(newSelButton);
                newSelButton.revalidate(); newSelButton.repaint();
            }
```